# Can GDAL ReprojectImage run multicore/multithread from python?

Tags: python, gdal

I am using GDAL in python to reproject an image. Is there a way to use all CPU cores in this process. I have tried the following with no success:

```
gdal.ReprojectImage(vrt, output, input_proj, ref_proj, gdalconst.GRA_Average, options=['NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS'])
```

I also tried including the NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS option to the output dataset:

```
output = driver.Create(fn, ref_x, ref_y, 1, gdalconst.GDT_Float32, options=['NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS'])
```

Comment: if you write up you commands in seperate bash files you can then use GNU parallel to run them in parallel in as many CPUs as you have

Comment: Is that if I am doing more than 1 task? This example is for one big task that I want to use multiple threads for.

Comment: But do you want to reproject one single image on multiple cores, or do you want to reproject a multitude of images on multiple cores? If the former - then this GNU parallel suggestion wouldn't work.

Comment: OK thanks for your insights. I want to be able to reproject a single image in multiple cores.

Comment: `gdal.SetConfigOption('GDAL_NUM_THREADS', '4')` See https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/alg/warp.py#L1073 for an example

Comment: This command is accepted but it doesn't seem to load up my CPUs any more. Just 1 sitting at 100%. Maybe I am missing something. Do I need to adjust memory somehow so it will take advantage of all CPUs?

Comment: @Ben, old post but you can increase gdal's block cache with `gdal.SetConfigOption('GDAL_CACHEMAX', '64')`. This would set it to 64MB for example.